# Word describing list of things discussed in a meeting that already happened

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

I attended a meeting and now I'd like to refer to the points discussed in it. I initially thought the term to be used in this context is "agenda". However, according to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://a%20list%20of%20matters%20to%20be%20discussed%20at%20a%20meeting:), "agenda" refers only to the list of matter that *will be discussed*.

> A list of matters to be discussed at a meeting.

It's not clear to me if one can also use "agenda" to refer to the list of items that were indeed discussed in a previous meeting. Maybe the agenda for the meeting was one, but the attendees actually ended up discussing more (or different) things. Can I use "agenda" to refer to the actual points that were discussed, or is there another word for this purpose?

Comment: 'Additions to last week's agenda' / 'the agenda as revised during the last meeting'.

Comment: The record of previous meetings is usually called the 'minutes'. One can refer to one's own record of a meeting as 'my minutes' or refer to official recording as 'the minutes'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agenda is what we plan to discuss.

The *minutes* report what we actually did discuss.  The term really means the official written record of the meeting, and with most important groups or boards, becomes a legal document. If you are looking for a totally informal term, there isn't one that I know of. Just say "We talked about ships, shoes and sealing-wax, but didn't decide what to do about any of them."